# What is the best way to handle the result between return or use innerhtml

Tags: javascript

Here is an example. I have a page with element with id weekday.
As I have done here I just add the result to the innerHTML for the id element weekday.

Now to my question is it more generic to just return
the actual day in the week for example Sunday and then use the innerHTML in the actual page
that is calling the Weekday function ?

What is your sugestion about this matter ?

```
function Weekday()
{
   var currentTime = new Date();

   //Get currrent day by indexing in the array
   var weekday = new Array(7);
   weekday[0] = "Monday";
   weekday[1] = "Tuesday";
   weekday[2] = "Wednesday";
   weekday[3] = "Thusday";
   weekday[4] = "Friday";
   weekday[5] = "Saturday";
   weekday[6] = "Sunday";

   document.getElementById("weekday").innerHTML = weekday[currentTime.getDay()] + ":"; 
}
```

//tony

Comment: This new Array(7) allocates seven element array

Comment: ok...well there is still no need...javascript arrays are dynamic by nature

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would create a function that returns only the weekday

---

*Explaining the arrays as there are many comments about* `new Array()`

`new Array()` is slower than `[]`

thats why i write

```
var weekdays=['Mo','Tu','We','Th','Fr','Sa','Su'];
```

then

```
var WD=weekdays[0] //is Mo
```

to have less vars

i add the `getDay()` inside the array index.

```
var WD=weekdays[new Date().getDay()]
```

and if we put all together we get.

```
var WD=['Mo','Tu','We','Th','Fr','Sa','Su'][new Date().getDay()]
```

---

and here is the function.

```
function getWDay(){
 return ['Mo','Tu','We','Th','Fr','Sa','Su'][new Date().getDay()]
}
```

and add the possibility to add a custom date.**so you can use it in other ways**

```
function getWDay(date){
 return ['Mo','Tu','We','Th','Fr','Sa','Su'][date.getDay()]
}
```

this allows you also to easely extend the function later.

```
function getWDay(date,length){
 return [
  'Monday',
  'Tuesday',
  'Wednesday',
  'Thusday',
  'Friday',
  'Saturday',
  'Sunday'
 ][date.getDay()].substr(0,length||10);
}
```

example

```
getWDay(new Date(),2).toUpperCase() // SA
getWDay(new Date(),3) // Sat
getWDay(new Date()) // Saturday
```

and then set it whenever you want

```
document.getElementById('day').innerText=getWDay(new Date()); //ie,webkit
document.getElementById('day').textContent=getWDay(new Date()); //moz,webkit
document.getElementById('day').innerHTML=getWDay(new Date()); //..mh
```

`return` is better in this case for utility function like this that you can use for various different things.

Answer (score 0):

If you create a function that just returns the weekday name then you can reuse that function in other places. Another option would be to pass in an argument of `id` and use that to select your element. Like so

```
function Weekday(id)
{
   var currentTime = new Date();

   //Get currrent day by indexing in the array
   var weekday = new Array(7);
   weekday[0] = "Monday";
   weekday[1] = "Tuesday";
   weekday[2] = "Wednesday";
   weekday[3] = "Thusday";
   weekday[4] = "Friday";
   weekday[5] = "Saturday";
   weekday[6] = "Sunday";

   document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = weekday[currentTime.getDay()] + ":"; 
}
```

I would compltely rewirte the function though like so

```
var weekday = (function() {    
    var weekday = ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thusday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"];
    return function(id) {       
       document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = weekday[new Date().getDay()] + ":"; 
    };
}());
```

You can do something like this now

```
weekday("myid");
```

Comment: Why did you used this constructor with a closure?

Comment: So that when the `weekday` function is called it does not constantly have to create an array. Instead it reuses the array created earlier. Also don't want anyone to have access to that array.

Comment: I knew that closure access is slower than local variables, but I was totally forgetting about the time to reallocate the array. The closure  is very fast compared to a plain function (at least in safari) http://jsperf.com/local-vs-closure-access

Comment: wow i did not know a site like this existed...i tested other browsers and you can view the results...closure performed better overall...thanks for showing me this site

Comment: I always set up tests like this when I'm not sure how I should implement something, I rather use the fastest instead of just randomly choosing one or the other implementation.